# Coldfusion indexing Corrupt File

Tags: pdf, solr, coldfusion, cfindex

Running a refresh on the first file then an update on all others. Recurse may not be necessary.

```
<cfindex
action=refresh
collection="this_name_solr"
key="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myappname\thefolder\thesubfolder\thefile.ext"
type="file"
urlpath="http://#application.root#/appname/thefolder/thesubfolder/thefile.ext"
extensions=".html, .htm, .xls, .xlsm, .doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt"
recurse="yes"
status="alldocs"
language="English">
```

Does fine until it hits a corrupt PDF File.  If I try to open the file manually in PDF reader I get the message that the file may be corrupt.

I need it to get past this file and continue indexing the rest. I have tried a request timeout of three minutes but that does not work.  I have attempted CFPDF Info extraction but it hangs reading it too.  I do not know how to test the doc to see if it is corrupt.

Ultimately I would like it to give up on the file after about 3 minutes.

Any suggestions

Comment: If you know what file it is, why don't you delete it?

Comment: Because i have 34000 files I am indexing and there may / probably are others

Comment: Some of my PDFs and Xls files are in the 100s of Megabytes but it seems to do ok with most of them.  Mainly the corrupt ones are just hanging, no log entry